# What standard PCB notes should I use?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

I have seen wide varieties at previous companies, from too few to too many with boilerplate, old revisions of standards, etc.  Can you suggest a middle of the road list?  This is for regular PCB fabrication for production.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that it's tempting to copy-and-paste fab notes from an existing design -- but those requirements may sometimes be contrary to your own interests.   Make sure that you agree with the details, especially when they reference a standard.  Otherwise, you may be spec'ing yourself to a more expensive board than you need!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is one I found](http://www.pcbdesignschool.com/2009/01/05/sample-fabrication-drawing-notes/) (free login required), but I don't know if it's good or complete.  I don't see UL-94V, for example.  *Printed Circuit Board Designer's Reference; Basics* gives [this example chapter](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0130674818/samplechapter/0130674818_ch02.pdf).

Comment: +1 for the note about "Thieving".  I always get a question from the Fab House about this.

Comment: The first link is dead. They probably moved it here: http://www.pcbdesignschool.com/?p=17

Answer (score 8):

**Identification**:

- client's name,
- (project ID),
- unique PCB ID

**PCB metrics**:

- material,
- CTI (Comparative Tracking Index),
- thickness,
- color,
- number of layers,
- layer stacking: reference to Gerber filename for each layer,
- copper thickness,
- solder mask color,
- silkscreen color

**Panelization**

- Tooling for PCB edges: V-cut or milling,
- PCB outline drawing with tolerances. This may be as simple as a rectangle, but [this board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyS5k.png)'s outline consists of 52 line segments

**Layout**

- If there's room for it some shops like to add a quality logo (like UL) and/or a production date to the silkscreen. Tell them which area of the PCB they can use for this.

Comment: I has to look this up "The Comparative Tracking Index or CTI is used to measure the electrical breakdown (tracking) properties of an insulating material." from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative_Tracking_Index

Answer (score 3):

- Board Name
- Company/personal name
- Copyright year
- Thickness
- Board material type
- Copper weight
- Panelization instructions
- Tolerances

Answer (score 3):

To what's already been mentioned, I'd add

- Surface finish (HASL, gold-plated, or ...)
- Lead free requirements or lack thereof
- Serialization requirements
- Allowed deviations from the design files (i.e., remove silkscreen from areas not covered by solder mask, etc.)
- color of solder mask
- Any specifications for controlled impedance (i.e. "tracks drawn as 4.05 mil wide on top layer shall be 50 Ohm controlled impedance +/- 10%")
- Tolerances for board dimensions, drill registration, drill diameter.
- Fire safety rating (e.g. 94V-0), if required.